# C/C++ double pointer de-referencing issue

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am facing an issue in de-referencing a value assigned to a pointer.

Considering the following function which works fine:

```
void encode(int32_t *pInput, unsigned char **ppOutput)
{
    **(int32_t **)ppOutput = *(int32_t*)pInput;
    *ppOutput += sizeof(int32_t);
}
```

Now, when I try to de-reference the value, using reverse logic as follows:

```
void decode(unsigned char **ppInput, int32_t *pOutput)
{
    *(int32_t *)pOutput = **(int32_t**)ppInput;

    *ppInput += sizeof(int32_t);
}



*(int32_t *)pOutput = **(int32_t**)ppInput;
```

then

```
*(int32_t *)pOutput
```

contains garbage, but if change the logic to,

```
*(int32_t *)pOutput = **ppInput;
```

then

```
*(int32_t *)pOutput
```

contains the correct value.

Please guide me where I am missing the clue.

Comment: I'm seeing more stars than inside a planetarium.  Don't use stars for emphasis in your post, as it makes the code look more confused than it is.

Comment: On the dereference side, i'm somewhat confident this: `**(int32_t**)ppInput` should in reality be this: `*(int32_t*)(*ppInput)`. Seeing *real* code in a *real* [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) woudl go a *long* way in clearing this up.

Comment: Why would you do such things? Don't.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Don't use stars, period. This includes code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 *(int32_t *)pOutput = **(int32_t**)ppInput;
```

You are casting pointer to `unsigned char*` into pointer to `int32_t*`. That is you are saying to read size of `int32_t` bytes from the memory location of `unsigned char` bytes. So, that's surely would give you garbage value as `sizeof(int32_t) > sizeof(unsigned char)`.

*An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a diﬀerent type. When a prvalue v of type “pointer to T1” is converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”, the result is static_cast(static_cast(v)) if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout types and the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1, or if either type is void. Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspeciﬁed.*

Comment: I've been looking at it for a little while now. My gut feeling is its undefined behavior. I wonder what the compiler warnings have to say about it... He should probably be using a `memmove` to avoid it....

Comment: OK, but I don't think the reason mentioned above should be an issue when ppOutput (from the encode function) is passed as ppInput in decode function. Assuming that ppOutput points to a pointer to char array of let's say size 4000 bytes.

For example,

unsigned char test[4000];
unsigned char * pEnc = test;
unsigned char **ppOutput = &pEnc;

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisArshad yeah that's not an issue over here...Cause of concern is the pointer conversion.

Comment: It's sort of obvious that you've allocated a buffer to accept the right size. But a MCVE would really help. I'm suspecting memory alignment. What (if any) are the alignment restrictions on your platform and have you dealt with that in your allocation of the buffer? However the only really portable way of doing this is `memmove` as advised by @jww or `memcpy` assuming the areas don't overlap (which appears to be the case).